Explicit or Implicit dependency: detekt Gradle Plugin: MultiModule Project
I have implemented the detekt plugin on multi module kotlin project. It is working fine when I run through gradlew command ./gradlew detektTask because it run as independent task but when I am running the build it show below error
Reason: Task ':detektTask' uses this output of task ':<module_name>:processInternalDebugGoogleServices' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency.


Project Level Gradle File
def detektTask = tasks.register('detektTask', Detekt) {
 setSource(files(rootProject.rootDir))

 // Specifying a baseline file. All findings stored in this file in subsequent runs of detekt.
 baseline = file("$rootDir/configuration/detekt/detekt-baseline.xml")

 // Define the detekt configuration(s) you want to use.
 config.setFrom(files("$rootDir/configuration/detekt/detekt.yml"))

 reports {
     html {
         enabled false
         outputLocation = file("build/reports/detekt/detektTask.html")
     }
 }

 include '**/*.kt'
 include '**/*.kts'
 exclude 'resources/'
 exclude 'build/'
}

allprojects {
 apply plugin: "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt"

 dependencies {
     detektPlugins(libs.detekt.formatting)
 }

 // Remove this line if we need to skip the detekt task during build
 tasks.configureEach {
     if (it.name == "compileKotlin") {
         it.dependsOn(detektTask)
         it.configure {
             shouldRunAfter(detektTask)
         }
     }
  }
}



